# Determine if a date is a Saturday or a Sunday using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

Is it possible to determine if a date is a **Saturday** or **Sunday** using JavaScript?

Do you have the code for this?

Answer (score 186, accepted):

Sure it is! The [`Date`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) class has a function called [`getDay()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getDay.asp) which returns a integer between 0 and 6 (0 being Sunday, 6 being Saturday). So, in order to see if today is during the weekend:

```
var today = new Date();
if(today.getDay() == 6 || today.getDay() == 0) alert('Weekend!');
```

In order to see if an arbitrary date is a weekend day, you can use the following:

```
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setFullYear(2009);
myDate.setMonth(7);
myDate.setDate(25);

if(myDate.getDay() == 6 || myDate.getDay() == 0) alert('Weekend!');
```

Comment: **@Steve:** I know, but for examples, it's usually better to be more verbose, in case someone doesn't know the order of the arguments.

Comment: Great answer @AndrewMoore!! Also worth mentioning that if you set the date manually, you need to subtract the month by 1 because it's a 0 index deal. So 0 = January, 1 = February and so on. :)

Answer (score 42):

You can simplify @Andrew Moore 's test even further:

```
if(!(myDate.getDay() % 6)) alert('Weekend!');
```

(Love that modulo function!)

Comment: Smart one :) I like it.

Comment: This is a more readable version: `const isWeekend = (date) => date.getDay() % 6 === 0`

Answer (score 10):

The Date class offers the getDay() Method that retrieves the day of the week component of the date as a number from 0 to 6 (0=Sunday, 1=Monday, etc)

```
var date = new Date();
switch(date.getDay()){
    case 0: alert("sunday!"); break;
    case 6: alert("saturday!"); break;
    default: alert("any other week day");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this is an elegant way to do this:

```
function showDay(d) {
    return ["weekday", "weekend"][parseInt(d.getDay() / 6)];
}

console.log(showDay(new Date()));
```

Comment: It doesn't quite work. It works for Saturday but Sunday returns as a weekday, not a weekend.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible, we can write a JavaScript code for that using JavaScript Date object.

Please use following JavaScript code.

> var d = new Date()
>
> document.write(d.getDay())

We can write a function to return the weekend in flag like below,
You can more customize the function to pass date. Or different return values for every day.

```
    isItWeekEnd = function() {
    var d = new Date();
    console.log(d.getDay());
    var dateValue = d.getDay(); 
    // dateValue : 0 = Sunday
    // dateValue : 6 = Saturday
    if(dateValue == 0 || dateValue == 6)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;  
}
```

Comment: where is sat & sunday?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the modulo answer... this one considers a range and attempt with performance as need to loop:

```js
export function getNumberWeekendsInRange(from: Date, to: Date): number {
  // 86400000 ms is 1 day
  const nFromDays = ~~(Number(from) / 86400000);
  const nToDays = ~~(Number(to) / 86400000);
  let numberOfWeekends = 0;

  for (let epochDay = nFromDays; epochDay < nToDays; epochDay++) {
    // epoch starts on a Thursday
    if (epochDay % 7 === 2 || epochDay % 7 === 3) ++numberOfWeekends;
  }

  return numberOfWeekends;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDay();
if(day==0){
 return false;
    //alert('sunday'); 
}
```

Comment: How does this add anything to the existing answers? (Let alone that it doesn't answer the full question)