# Time Script Within Header of Page

Tags: javascript, php, timing

I need to time a script in my header to only display between 8:00 am and 5:30 PM Monday - Friday. It needs to remain in the header for templating purposes.

The script is the following:

```
<head><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/chat/scripts/livechat.js"></script></head>
```

Now I would normally take the following approach, but it doesn't apply because this is not a div:

```
<script>// get current time
var d = new Date(), 
hours = d.getHours(),
mins = d.getMinutes();
day = d.getDay();   

// if day is mon-fri and time is between 8am and 5:30pm
if(0 < day < 6   
    && hours >= 8 
    && (hours < 17 || hours === 17 && mins <= 30)){

    $('.mydiv').show(); 
 };</script>
```

I'm confused as to how to make this work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have small mistake in if. `0 < day < 6` is incorrect in JS.

```
if((day > 0 && day < 6  ) 
    && hours >= 8 
    && (hours < 17 || hours === 17 && mins <= 30)){

    $('.mydiv').show(); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this on the client side via Javascript has the drawback that users can hack into the code and change and make it load even though, perhaps one solution would be to treat that single line in a server side generated HTML
and send it back with or without that line, 
for example if you are using Java and JSP you can calulcate the condition in java and store it on a configuration object like:

```
<c:if test="{myappConfig.isLiveChatEnabled eq true}
//... include JS file
</c:if>
```

but if you want to do it via JS you can take a look at [Determine if a date is a Saturday or a Sunday using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181219/determine-if-a-date-is-a-saturday-or-a-sunday-using-javascript) it would help to build the conditional statement.

Comment: What is your suggestion for the server side generated HTML?

Comment: if you're using JSP or Java you can have a properties file stored on the server side and then apply an if condition like in the comment above