# Get current sunday for giving date using Moment js library

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to get the **current sunday** by giving a date inside the current week, but unfortunately I'm always getting the next sunday.

```
let sundayDate = moment(date).day(7).toDate();
```

As far as I know, there is a difference of 0 and 7, but this peace of code do work for my colleagues. I do checked our timezones and languages but there is no diffrence between us. I used `let sundayDate = moment(date).day(0).toDate();` it did work for us, but I'm wondering why the first one is not working for me. Regarding the [moment documentation day of week](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/).

> moment().day(0); // this Sunday (0)
> moment().day(7); // next Sunday (0 + 7)

```
isSunday(date: Date):boolean{
  console.log("my giving sunday date",date)
  let sundayDate = moment(date).day(7).toDate();
  console.log("moment sunday date reference",sundayDate)
  if (date.getTime() === sundayDate.getTime()) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

[image: CODE LOGS]
I'm trying to have a stable solution for this issue !
PS : Sunday is the last day of week in my case, that would be better if I can treat the other case, being sunday the first day of week.

Comment: If you just need to check if a Date object was on a Sunday, you can use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181219/determine-if-a-date-is-a-saturday-or-a-sunday-using-javascript

Comment: Your difference is in your PS. Sunday being the last day of the week. You're probably better off using [`moment(date).isoWeekday(7)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/iso-weekday/).

Comment: Also, if you find yourself using `if (condition) { return true } else { return false }` you can just write `return condition`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, it works perfectly, well I'm expecting in case of `moment(date).isoWeekday(0)` to get the sunday day itself, but I get the previous sunday. Is there any control on this case, cause I see just 2 values (1,7) regarding the doc?

Comment: 0 is not a supported ISO Weekday value. Use the string, `"Sunday"` (or whatever it is in the language of your users) if you prefer. If you're getting the wrong Sunday consistently, add or subtract a week to the date passed in before taking the weekday.